# PowerShell Timing Script

Tags: windows, powershell

Trying to take the following output (listed below) from a PS script and create another output file 
stating the time it took for each step to complete. Time is in format of day:hr:min:sec

```
Current output:
[Cpu 1] at [Step 1] completed at 120:15:12:15
[Cpu 1] at [Step 2] completed at 120:15:17:18
[Cpu 1] at [Step 3] completed at 120:16:37:13
```

Since Step 2 finished at 120:15:17:18, the total time would be found by 120:15:17:18 - 120:15:12:15.
Step 3 finished at 120:16:37:13, so the total time would be found by 120:16:37:13 - 120:15:17:18.

```
Desired output: 
'Step 2 took xx:xx:xx:xx to complete'
'Step 3 took xx:xx:xx:xx to complete'
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? how does your script look and what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: what are the time units? the ones you show are not standard ones ... [*grin*]

Comment: Show your code that creates this output. For the most part, you should be able to leverage the [Measure-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7) cmdlet for what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Use ...

[Measure-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7)

```
# Examples
Measure-Command { Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Windows\*.txt -Recurse }

Measure-Command {Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse}

10, 20, 50 | Measure-Command -Expression { for ($i=0; $i -lt $_ i++) {$i} }

10, 20, 50 | Measure-Command -Expression {for ($i=0; $i -lt $_; $i++) {$i}; "$($_)" | Out-Default }
```

... and use the TotalMilliseconds property as your result.

Or use a stopwatch in your code block to get the elapsed time.

```
# Instantiate and start a new stopwatch
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
```

> [Stopwatch Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1)
>
> [Stopwatch.StartNew Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew?view=netcore-3.1)
>
> [PowerShell - Measure Script execution time](https://pscustomobject.github.io/powershell/howto/Measure-Script-Time/)